# Mixed https content in SSL secure site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, ssl, https, mixed-content

I have just made my WordPress site secure with an SSL certificate and the website is working fine. I purchased the SSL and then used a plugin to activate the SSL and another plugin "Better Search Replace" to replace every entry in the database with http.

My homepage is working perfect with https, however, the rest of the pages give a mixed content error because of this:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.cmiuniversal.com/empresas/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.cmiuniversal.com/wp-content/themes/kudos/assets/img/preload_pattern.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

The thing is. That image should be loaded with https and if I copy that URL with https I can acces the image without a problem. I don't understand why it is calling the http version of it.

Because of this image my entire site (excluding my home page is not loading as secure).

I have tried different plugins and I have also forced the SSL with Cloudflare with the SSL options and adding an always use https page rule.

Nothing seems to work and I don't know what else to do

The site is: 
https://www.cmiuniversal.com/

And any page that is not the homepage has the problem. Like this one:
https://www.cmiuniversal.com/empresas/

Comment: Firefox devtools seems to indicate the problem is caused by the code at line 3 column 27482 of the file at https://www.cmiuniversal.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js. That code is minimized so who knows what it might be doing.

Comment: at the moment i get a database connection error message when I click any of your nav links.  so you need to fix that issue first.

Comment: Yes @JustinR. that was a problem yesterday night because of Cloudflare. Should be working now.